# Chrome can't send data greater 128KB by Websocket?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I want to send big data from browser to Server Websocket C++ (I use Poco library to make Server). When I test with Firefox and Edge, It work perfectly. But when I test with Chrome, data can't be greater than 128KB. I tested demo in echo.websocket.org and Java Websocket Server too and receive a same result. Anyone can help me to fix this? (Sorry about my English)

Comment: Does your server handle fragmented messages? Chrome will split up messages larger than 128KB into multiple (fragmented) messages.

Comment: I found my problem, Tks u very much :D